# Elasticsearch Pagination - Last Page Returning Too Many Results

Tags: java, elasticsearch

My Elasticsearch query is returning 111 results, which means that if I'm paging through them (with 10 results per page) I should have 12 pages: 11 full pages and 1 page with a single result.

However, my last page is still returning 10 results. It's returning the very last result as expected, but also 9 results from the previous page. How do I disable this behavior and have it just return the single result as expected?

I'm using the Java API, with the following code:

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("my_index")
   .setTypes("my_output")
   .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
   .setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(query))
   .setFrom(page).setSize(size)
   .execute()
   .actionGet();
```

Comment: Can you show how you define the `page` and `size` variables?

Comment: They're taken directly from @PathParam variables. Size is generally set to 10 (the default), and page is a 0-based number (0 for page 1, 11 for page 12).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `from` parameter in the ES query is not a page number but an offset. So if you want the 11th page, `from` must be 110 (assuming `size` is 10) and not 11.

So you can keep passing a page number using `@PathParam`, but the value you pass to `setFrom()` must be `page * size` and not just `page`.

So for `page = 0`, you'll call `setFrom(0)`, for `page = 1` you'll call `setFrom(10)`, etc and for `page = 11` (i.e. the 12th page), you'll call `setFrom(110)`.

Comment: Here is the relevant Javadoc: http://javadoc.kyubu.de/elasticsearch/v1.7.1/org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchRequestBuilder.html#setFrom%28int%29   I don't know why the ES site doesn't host the Javadoc themselves but the person that runs the site I linked to is good about adding new versions.

Comment: The official documentation for the [`from` and `size` parameters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html#search-uri-request) is the main "goto" resource. All clients (Java or otherwise) implement the exact same requirements.